# Mvp в android pattern

Tags: java, android

Когда мы используем `mvp`, у нас есть `presenter`, `model` и `view`.

`Presenter` взаимодействует с `model`. 
Если у нас есть 2 `EditText` в активности, данные, которых мы должны считать, то мы создаем две переменных. 
В `presenter` я также создаю эти переменные и создаю конструктор, потом при создании объекта `presenter` во `view`, я передаю 2 переменные `view`, которые инициализируются в `presenter` и идет работа с реальными данными, все правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: Т.е вы передаете EditText в презентер?

Comment: @temq да, именно

Answer (score 2):

Вообще лучше при реализации презентера делать так, что бы он не знал что он работает в системе Android. Т.е. передавать туда всякие view, контексты и другие компоненты Android системы не надо. В вашем случае достаточно сделать в презентере метод который принимает два строковых аргумента. Дальше view ждет какого то события от пользователя, к примеру нажатия кнопки, передает данные, считанные с текстовых полей, в презентер. После этого презентер анализирует эти данные, делает с ними что-то и вызывает у view метод, который отобразит результат работы.